# How to select all the elements which class starts with GB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I have a project In which i want to select all the elements that have following classes:
 `.GB1, .GB2, .GB3, .GB4, .GB5` and this will continue until `.GB400`.
I also have other elements which contain the following types of classes `.GB, .GBholder, .GB_color, .GB-size` and I don't want to select this elements. I don't have any other element classes which starts with `.GB` and after `.GB` it have number like `.GB1` or `GB20`. So I have a idea. But I don't know how to do this with jquery or javascript.The idea is "I Will tell the browser that, select all the elements that started with `.GB` and after `.GB` It have one or many numbers." Is it possible? How can I do it via js or jquery?

Here is the code I am trying now:

```
$('.color').on('click', function() {
    $('*[class^="GB"]').css("background-color","red");
})
```

I have already wrote all the html and some long css by this classes. So It will take too many time change this class names.

Comment: While this is possible the code will be ugly and not very performant. If possible, it would be *much* better to amend your HTML to add a class to the elements the you want to select directly.

Comment: I have already wrote all the html and some long css by this classes. So It will take too many time change this class names.

Comment: This works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1y6dpLzk/

Comment: Your site will be hard to maintain. BTW, your title question is quite misleading with your expected behaviour, you just don't want what your title is asking for...

Comment: Thanks @ A. Wolff for your comment. Actually I Don't Find any other title for this question. Please feel free to correct the title. or suggest me I will change it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `isNaN()` method like following.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="GB1">GB1</div>
<div class="GB2">GB2</div>
<div class="GB3">GB2</div>
<div class="GBholder">GB holder</div>
<div class="GB_color">GB color</div>
<input type="button" value="Click" class="color"/>

<script>
    $('.color').on('click', function () {
        $('[class^="GB"]').filter(function () {
            return isNaN($(this).attr('class').slice(2)) == false;

            //if your elements has more than one class then add GB first and try this
            //var cl = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
            //return isNaN(cl.slice(2)) == false;
        }).css("background-color", "red");
    })
</script>
```

Comment: as a note: `$(this).attr('class')` is completely wasteful. `this.className` will contain the same information in this example and doesn't require you re-wrap things with jQuery.

Comment: I gave you credit but this would fail for `<div class="GB ">`, isNaN() should be replaced by `Number.isNan()`  EDIT: in fact no...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. `this.className` is better but `$(this).attr('class')` is not completely wasteful. @rlemon

Comment: it is wasteful, it does the same thing with more work.. that is wasteful.

Comment: @rlemon Some developpers like to keep coding syntax consistent, meaning using appropriate library method, not mixing it. But in this case it doesn't really matter indeed

Comment: but that isn't consistent. `$(this).prop('id')` is never correct over `this.id`. It isn't 'coding syntax', it is invoking a method which is not needed and not helpful. This isn't the place for this discussion however, I just wanted to make a note about your code for OP. carry on.

Comment: @rlemon That's not my code ;) Just think about it, difference between `this.href` & `$(this).attr('href')`. Or even in some cases between `this.value` & `$(this).val()`